# Child rigidbody2D doesn't rotate while parent is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem: I have created a parent sprite which moves forever to the left. I have created a child sprite to it, which I want to rotate. When the parent doesn't move the child rotates, but as soon as the parent starts moving - the child freezes.

```
[Parent] <- Rigidbody (kinematic), moved via rigidbody2D.velocity = movementSpeed
   |
[Child] <- Rigidbody (kinematic) rotation via rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = rotationSpeed
```

I know I can call transform.Rotate during FixedUpdate, but I would like to avoid it and to set the velocity at Start or OnEnable. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: Have you tried using AddTorque (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddTorque.html) instead?

Comment: Nope, I decided to move it via transform.rotation or animator as that object ended up not to need a rigidbody.